# GCC invalid constant string layout

Tags: objective-c, gcc

I'm trying to implement my own string class on Linux using GCC's `-fconstant-string-class` option. The layout of my class is as follows

```
@interface String : RootObject //my root object class; it is essentially NSObject
{ 
    char *c_string;
    unsigned int len;
}
```

This is exactly the way [GCC tells me to implement this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Constant-string-objects.html) (the `isa` ivar is inherited from the `RootObject` class), but when I attempt to use a string literal (`@"foo"`), GCC gives me the following error upon compilation

```
error: interface String does not have a valid constant string layout
```

A Google search gave me [this link](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/gnustep-dev/2007-08/msg00003.html), but it seems as though the asker never solved his problem. The only other ivar the class contains is a `volatile int retainCount` inherited from the superclass.

Comment: @JoshCaswell that was the issue. Removing that ivar solved my problem, so, if you want, you can post your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: Sweet! Answer posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `retainCount` ivar is not included in the specification you quoted. [GNU's `Object` class doesn't have it](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/gcc/gcc-5484/libobjc/objc/Object.h), and note that in Cocoa, which springs from the same NeXTian origin as GNU's ObjC library, [`-retainCount` is part of the `NSObject` *protocol*](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/retainCount), not the class.

This is likely to be your problem, as inheriting it from your root class puts it before the `c_string` and `len` fields, screwing up the expected layout.

Removing it should allow this to work.